# How can I trigger a transition effect when a child control is added or removed in flex?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3

I've got a custom component that has children components dynamically added and removed to it depending on what button the user clicks. What I would like to do is trigger a transition effect that moves the child component onto the stage when it's added and then moves it off when it's removed.

Does anyone have a good example on how to accomplish this?

Edit: I figured it out and left my solution below. I hope it helps someone else!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just figured out how to get this working. Here's the answer I came up with. I hope that it helps someone else that has the same question!

`MyContainerComponent` is the parent control I'm adding the children controls to and `MyCustomChildControl` is the control I want to show the transitions for. The `moveIn` and `moveOut` arguments are the transition effects I've created.

```
public function AddChildComponent():void
{
  var newChild:MyCustomChildControl= new MyCustomChildControl();

  newChild.name = "ChildControl";
  newChild.setStyle("addedEffect", moveIn);
  newChild.setStyle("removedEffect", moveOut);
  MyContainerComponent.addChild(newChild);
}
```